# как преобразовать данные типа integer, которые считываются с консоли, в тип string?

Tags: php

требуется для решения этой задачи:  На вход дается целых чисел n и m. Вывести чисел от 0 до 1000, у которых в значениях есть хотя бы одна цифра n, и не делятся на m.

```
<?php
fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d", $n, $m);
for($i = 0;$i < 1000; $i++){
    $str = $i;
    if($i % $m == 0 && strpos($str , $n) !== false){
        echo $i . " "; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, для преобразования к строке можно использовать `strval()`.

```
$str = strval($i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использую явное приведение типа:

```
const _numder = 12;
const _null = null;

var_dump(((string)_numder));
var_dump(((string)_null));
```

[Документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php).